# Submit form to another page within the same domain

Tags: forms, form-submit

How to submit form to another page within the same domain which has no form ID or name?

Form that needs to submit to another page:

```
<form id="login_form" action="roundcube" method="post">
    <div class="input-req-login">
        <label for="user">Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon username-container">
        <input name="_user" 
               id="rcmloginuser" 
               autofocus="autofocus" 
               placeholder="Enter your email address." 
               class="std_textbox" 
               type="text"  
               tabindex="1" required>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px;" class="input-req-login">
        <label for="pass">Parola</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon password-container">
        <input name="_pass" 
               id="rcmloginpwd" 
               placeholder="Enter your email password." 
               class="std_textbox" 
               type="password"
               tabindex="2" required>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="login-btn">
            <button type="submit" 
                    onclick="document.getElementByName("form").submit()"  
                    tabindex="3">Autentificare</button>
         </div>
```

Target form:

```
<form name="form" action="./" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="543e98f5e6cc25841fc0df79cb939590">
    <input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_">
    <input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl" value="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td  class="title">
                    <label for="rcmloginuser">Utilizator</label>
                </td>
                <td class="input">
                    <input name="_user" 
                        id="rcmloginuser" 
                        size="40" 
                        autocapitalize="off"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">
                    <label for="rcmloginpwd">Parolă</label>
                </td>
                <td class="input">
                    <input name="_pass" 
                           id="rcmloginpwd" 
                           size="40" 
                           autocapitalize="off"
                           autocomplete="off" 
                           type="password">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="formbuttons">
        <input type="submit" 
               class="button mainaction"
               value="Autentificare" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Need to know a lot more to answer. For example what language are you using? Why do you have 2 forms? What page is intended as the target of your form? What is afterlogic?

Comment: I edit it the code, I have found roundcoube mail has form name but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have taken a look at your sites now. This is actually quite simple.

I guess what you are trying to do is to set up a personalized web site to log in so you can give your own look and feel. And roundcube, I guess that is a standard mail system you have installed?

Well the problem is that roundcube not only sends user name and password. If you look at the HTML code you also see:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="5b6a757df5eee91fa7ee7171466b8b2a">
<input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_">
<input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl" value="">
```

All these are hidden values that are automatically sent with the log in POST. You probably need to add the last 4 of them.

There might be a big problem for you though. The first one called _token I have a theory that this is a randomized string that the server will require you to provide. I can be wrong but if I am correct you will not be able to do what you want. The reason for having this random string is to prevent users from posting log ins from other forms (that is if I am correct)

Maybe it is possible for you to turn off this randomized string in the roundcube admin settings? If not I think you don't have an easy way to proceed unless you want to dig into the code of round cube.

Edit: I just tried submitting the original form without the _token and it does not work. so unfortunately you are out of luck this time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your question, but I guess you are writing a new page and want to post to another page. What if you do like this?

```
<form id="login_form" action="http://webmail.mysite.com/roundcube/" method="post">
```

Comment: I just did that, new page with roundcube opens but only user field is present , password not and also not submited. I need to login from page1 to page2 and open page2 which should be logged in.